# Need explanation some terms in python code

Tags: python, string

this is my code

```
'''Nimal,30,60
   Saman,80,45
   Upali,100,80
   above text is in input.txt
   '''
f1 = open('input.txt','r')
f2 = open('output.txt','w')
line = f1.readline()
while(line):
    data = (line.strip()).split(',')
    total = float(data[1])+float(data[2])
    f2.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(data[0],data[1],data[2],total))
    line=f1.readline()
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

I need to know `while(line)` how become true and what happen in below line

```
   f2.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(data[0],data[1],data[2],total))
```

Comment: Are you facing any errors? Don't really understand what you are asking here.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid 
this is an Exam question

Comment: So what is the question? I mean, are you asking what that line of code is doing? Its just writing data to the output file.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid dont comment as such a stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, line is a string. In python, a string will be evaluated as False if it's an empty string, say `''`. Otherwise, it will be evaluated as True.

What `f2.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(data[0],data[1],data[2],total))` does is to fill the four `{}` with the corresponding values given in the format function, and then write out to `f2`. For example, `f2.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format('Nimal', 1, 2, 3))` will be formalized as a string `'Nimal,1,2,3\n'` without quotes, and then write this string into file `f2`.

Comment: Thnx I got it buddy